# Not able to start solr in windows

Tags: solr

I have downloaded solr 6.4.0 version and tried starting using solr start from bin directory I end up with following error:

C:\solr-6.4.0\bin>solr start
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\solr-6.4.0\bin>

Could you please advise me is there any configuration that i need to do/ how to start?
Thanks.

Comment: from solr home directory try this command `bin\solr start -p 8983`

Comment: Does just "findstr" at the command line works? It should be available in most windows installations.

Comment: How exactly (very exactly) are you running the start command. From CMD, from PowerShell, double-clicking or something else. Also, which exactly version of Windows are you on.

Comment: I am using cmd.exe from the start menu and go the directory bin of solr where I placed and then firing the command solr start. I am using windows 7. Please advise.

Comment: Hi Vinod, I also tried  what you suggested but no fruitful outcome.                      C:\solr-6.4.0>bin\solr start -p 8993
'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Please advise

Answer (score 1):

The program findstr.exe can be found in C:\Windows\system32. 
Check if you can find it there.

If it is available, modify your "path" environment variable to include the path "C:\Windows\system32\".

If you have an open command prompt window, exit and re-open it, and check that the %PATH% variable contains the newly added path.

```
echo %PATH%
```

Now "findstr.exe" should be available for Solr scripts.

Answer (score 0):

- Download solr + copy downloaded folder to c: drive (solr7.2.1)
- Download nssm installer + copy downloaded folder to  c: drive (solr)
- open nssm installer in cmd:

  ```
            >> cd C:\solr\nssm2.24\win64
            >> nssm install solr7
  ```
- GUI service Installer opens (Enter solr path details)

  ```
  - C:\solr-7.2.1\bin\solr.cmd
  - C:\solr-7.2.1\bin
  ```
- Install (solr as service gets installed)
- Set Environment Variable -> System Variables (JRE Path):

  ```
  JAVA_HOME: c:\ProgramFiles\java\jre1.8.0_212
  ```
- Check if solr is running (from services)
- Open Solr:
  https://localhost:8983/solr/#/

Answer (score -1):

Actually findstr.exe is missing.

So follow these steps:

1.go to C:\Windows\system32\ and copy findstr.exe file.
2. paste this file into the location C:\Program Files\Java\jdk{version}\bin

Then run the this command:

```
solr.cmd start
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried solr.cmd start but still the same error:                                           C:\solr-6.4.0\bin>solr.cmd start
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.